# VSCode's Go to definition navigates to @types/react instead of the real definition

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use the latest VSCode version.
Currently, VSCode jumps to `@types/react` instead of its component file if a component use `FC` from `react`.
It happens recently, and before it worked well.

Does anyone meet with the same problem and how to fix it?

[image]

I downloaded 1.85.2 and 1.84.2, and then replace the app.
However, it didn't work. (I'm not sure VSCode has cache...?)

Anyway, I use "editor.gotoLocation.multipleDefinitions": "goto".
Both @types/react and real definision are shown if it changes to peek.

So, it would be change the priority result of peek...?

---

I checked the following settings but still not work well.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you.
This screenshot is the result of `go to definition`.

Comment: One thing I noticed, if you go to on the closing tag it goes to the correct location. It only fails on the opening tag

Comment: I tried too. Interestingly, it's true.
closing tag can navigate to the correct location but opening tag not.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately developers did not think about the other extensions so settings work only for `.js`/`.ts` files.

To make it work with react files we need to add a rule for `.tsx` files manually.

Add next string to your user/workspace settings json:

```
"typescriptreact.preferGoToSourceDefinition": true,
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! Worth noting my vscode highlighted it with a warning: `Unknown Configuration Setting` but it still worked :p

Comment: As of yesterday, this setting breaks my `node_modules` "click through". I need `"typescriptreact.preferGoToSourceDefinition": true` for `src`, but `"typescriptreact.preferGoToSourceDefinition": false`  for `node_modules`.

Comment: Jumping to a component from `node_modules` will be to `.js` code instead of type. It is slightly inconvenient yet.
However, I can jump to components that I created manually  by this setting.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me this morning.
Fixed with Go to Source Definition: https://d.pr/i/DcAhBB

Comment: Please only use the official image host by simply pasting your image into your question. That's the only way to guarantee that your image will be available to future visitors.